# C# Task & Await calling my function twice

Tags: c#

I am rarely use task / await to call my function. please have a look at my code example. i am using .net v4.5.2.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bool retvalue = false;
     var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
     var task1 = SimulateJob(); 
     var task2 = Task.Delay(periodTimeSpan);
     await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
     retvalue = (bool) task1.Result;
}

private Task<bool> SimulateJob()
{
     bool status = false;

     Task.Delay(10000);
     status = true;

    return Task.FromResult(status);
}
```

please run the code and understand that **SimulateJob() function** getting called twice.

in really my **SimulateJob() function** loads big excel file into spread sheet control. if that function gets called twice then it will be problem for me.

how to change my code in such a way that when this line will execute **await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);** then my **SimulateJob() function** will be called.

in real code **SimulateJob() function** load multiple big excel file. i saw when this line execute **var task1 = SimulateJob();** then my routine load all those big files which is my problem. i want that when this line would execute `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` then my **SimulateJob function** should load those big excel file. so tell me what i need to change in my code example.

please help me to handle this situation. thanks

Comment: it is not called twice

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by delaying 10 seconds in task 2? Do you want to wait your current thread until you complete your function `SimulateJob`?

Comment: @AbhilashAugustine yes i want to execute SimulateJob() after that 10 sec will be delay. but i saw SimulateJob() calling twice when i debug code line by line.

Comment: in real code SimulateJob() function load multiple bug excel file. i saw when this line `var task1 = SimulateJob(); ` then my routine load all those big files which is my problem. i want that when this line would execute ` await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` then my SimulateJob function should load those big excel file. so tell me what i need to change. thanks

Comment: Be clear - neither `await` nor `WhenAll` are responsible for *starting* anything. You give them *already running* `Task`s, and they wait for them to finish. It sounds like you `SimulateJob` method, despite returning a `Task` is actually synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool retvalue = await SimulateJob();
            Console.WriteLine(retvalue); // this line of code will execute after excel file loaded
        }

    private async Task<bool> SimulateJob()
    {
        bool status = false;

        await Task.Delay(10000); // call your asynchronus excel loading here
        status = true; // once it's done,  then set status to true

        return status;
    }
```

this is how you can call an asynchronous function from your button click handler. No need to register unwanted task to just delay for 10 seconds.

Use keyword `async` on your asynchronous function definition like above.

Comment: ok thanks i will follow your approach. if any problem occur then i will let you know. thanks

Comment: Assuming you can await something in `SimulateJob()`. You can just `Task.Run()` it.

Comment: i can not use Task.Run() because i am using devexpress spreadsheet control and it does not support thread.

Comment: Of course you can. When you `await Task.Run(()=> SomeMethod())`, the continuation is resumed in the UI Thread. It's the same thing. I hope you're not trying to access a Control in an async method, it doesn't make any sense.